# Application suddenly stopped POSTing to DB, returning Status Code 406

Tags: php, android, arrays

My Application makes calls to our server through a couple different `Asynctask`'s, it pulls data twice and finally sends a `JSONArray` through POST.

It had been working properly but recently stopped, no changes were made. Here is my `AsyncTask` to `POST` a `JSONArray` with only the necessary information:

**UPDATED JAVA**

```
String inString;
JSONObject realjObject;
JSONArray compJArray;
int completeCount = 0;
URL url;
@Override
protected Void doInBackground(JSONArray... jsonArray) {
    if(jsonArray.length > 0) {
        compJArray = jsonArray[0];
    }
    completeCount = compJArray.length();

    //String url_select = "http://www.myDomain.com/db/completedSurvey.php";
    HttpResponse response;

    for (int i = 0; i < completeCount; i++) {
        try {
            realjObject = compJArray.getJSONObject(i);
            Log.i("realjObject", realjObject.toString());
            try {

                url = new URL("http://www.myDomain.com/db/completedSurvey.php");
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url.toURI());
                HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                httpPost.setEntity(new StringEntity(realjObject.toString(), "UTF-8"));
                httpPost.setHeader(HTTP.DEFAULT_CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json");
                response = (HttpResponse) httpClient.execute(httpPost);

                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent(), "UTF-8"));
                StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
                for (String line = null; (line = reader.readLine()) != null;) {
                    builder.append(line).append("\n");
                }

                inString = builder.toString();
                Log.w("RESPONSE", inString);

            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e1) { Log.e("UnsupportedEncodingException", e1.toString());
            } catch (ClientProtocolException e2) { Log.e("ClientProtocolException", e2.toString());
            } catch (IllegalStateException e3) { Log.e("IllegalStateException", e3.toString());
            } catch (IOException e4) { Log.e("IOException", e4.toString());
            } catch (URISyntaxException e) {Log.e("URISyntaxException", "" + e.getMessage());
            }

        } catch (JSONException e) { Log.e("doInBackground", "JSONException: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

---

And here is how I am receiving the code, PHP-Server side:

```
require("../logger/logging.class.php");

$genLog->lwrite("Is Android accessing this url?");
$json = file_get_contents('php://input');

$genLog->lwrite($json);

if ($json) {
    // Parse JSONArray, was working properly
}
```

My log is writing perfectly fine if the I access the url through the browser, however nothing is written when running the application. I have tested all output in the `AsyncTask` and everything seems to work properly.

---

`LogCat` output of `realjObject` *(Verified on www.jsonlint.com)*:

```
{
    "Notes": "null",
    "SurveyPhoto": "null",
    "id": 2,
    "siteNotes": "",
    "loc_id": 1,
    "sign_type": "FREESTANDING SIGN",
    "Lighting": 0,
    "AdditionalService": 0,
    "view_id": 2,
    "survey_order": 1
}
```

---

**Edit**

I just started thinking that my `require("../logger/logging.class.php");` might conflict with `$json = file_get_contents('php://input');`, but I just commented out all of my logging and require lines and it still isn't doing anything.

Device has internet connection and has an established connection with this MySQL database or I wouldn't get a point of being able to submit the `JSONArray`.

Test Device: Samsung Galaxy Tab 10.1 Gen 1 running Android 4.0.1

**Edit 2**

I fixed the `InputStream` to give me a response and got the following 404 & 406 response:

```
12-05 09:31:39.345: W/RESPONSE(19023): <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
12-05 09:31:39.345: W/RESPONSE(19023): <html><head>
12-05 09:31:39.345: W/RESPONSE(19023): <title>406 Not Acceptable</title>
12-05 09:31:39.345: W/RESPONSE(19023): </head><body>
12-05 09:31:39.345: W/RESPONSE(19023): <h1>Not Acceptable</h1>
12-05 09:31:39.345: W/RESPONSE(19023): <p>An appropriate representation of the requested resource /db/completeSurvey.php could not be found on this server.</p>
12-05 09:31:39.345: W/RESPONSE(19023): <p>Additionally, a 404 Not Found
12-05 09:31:39.345: W/RESPONSE(19023): error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.</p>
12-05 09:31:39.345: W/RESPONSE(19023): <hr>
12-05 09:31:39.345: W/RESPONSE(19023): <address>Apache Server at www.myDomain.com Port 80</address>
12-05 09:31:39.345: W/RESPONSE(19023): </body></html>
```

What could suddenly cause this?

**EDIT 3** - Recent steps I took to troubleshoot:

1. I have contacted our web host and they are telling me everything on their end is fine.
   The server logs (error_log) don't show any errors
2. I have slightly changed the above Java to show my response return as well as changing to using `URL` class rather then `String` for the `new HttpPost(url.toURI());`. LogCat shows the correct domain, copied and pasted into browser, works fine.
3. I have changed the URL to another file with the `/db/completeSurvey.php` contents placed into the new file, same 404/406 response as above.
4. I created another new php file only containing an `fwrite` to log page call, same 404/406 response as above.
5. I directed to our root domain, "http://www.myDomain.com", same 404/406 response as above

I'm starting to think that it has to be either the device or my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I contacted our Web Host (Surpass Hosting) and gave them the following message:

> 406 Not Acceptable
>
> An appropriate representation of the requested resource /db/completedSurvey.php could not be found on this server.
>
> Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
>
> Apache Server at www.myDomain.com Port 80

At first they said that I needed to write more logging code to determine what the cause was because it wasn't on their end.

Eventually I finally got sent to Tech Support Level II, the guy there gave me the answer immediately:

---

**Solution:**

> Surpass Tech:
>   "This was due to the script matching a rule in mod_security. I've disabled only this rule for that file."

Answer (score 1):

what are you trying to do with this line `inString = in.toString();`? you are calling `toString()` on `InputStream` it would not return response data.

Try the following code to read the json:

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent(), "UTF-8"));
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
for (String line = null; (line = reader.readLine()) != null;) {
    builder.append(line).append("\n");
}

inString = builder.toString();
```

Comment: I'm not doing anything with it right now, eventually I am going to get to a point where I am returning a response code of successful or not. My `AsyncTask` has not changed from working to not working. This can't be the issue.

Comment: still trying to understand the problem. what is `AsyncTask` not working?. please show the code to store data which is not working?

Comment: The store data is very long and hasn't changed since it was working, for some reason I am not even getting to this point. I can still post it, I just didn't want to deter people from helping due to a long question.

Comment: are you getting http 200 response? is there any exception? its hard to see any problem without more detail?

Comment: See edit to OP, I am getting a 404 & 406 response, I don't understand what would suddenly cause this

Comment: ahh so it is not able to find the php file.. can you try the same url on browser to see if it working there? where are you running your server... is it on the same machine?

Comment: Ah, good thinking, I hadn't thought about accessing the URL from the device's browser... I just accessed the URL from the browser on the device and it logged properly, tried the app again and got the same response code.

Comment: so it is working from browser but not from the app? where are you running the server?

Comment: Correct, and the server is being hosted by www.surpasshosting.com.

Comment: I checked the server error_log and there was nothing pertaining to this. I contacted our Web Host and they are saying it is on my end. I updated the OP to show what I have tried since yesterday's discussion. I am lost.

Comment: one more things that can be tried.. try to replicate the browser by adding all the header that the browser is sending... browser header can be checked by going to following URL http://www.reliply.org/tools/requestheaders.php .. just to check that may be server allows request from browser but not not from application...

Comment: Good find! Thank you, I sent a request for this site from my application & device browser to that site and it, with it I found that my application was sending a User-Agent of `Apache-HttpClient/UNAVAILABLE (java 1.4)`, is this UNAVAILABLE my issue? Is this normal.

Comment: normally I don't set the user agent from application. so API send whatever default user agent it has... but in some cases where server blocks request that does not have expected user agent.. I either hard code the user agent or create using the API (like os version, device name etc) and ask the server team to support that user agent..

did you try sending the headers from the application? if yes; did that work?

Comment: Yeah I sent the headers from my application to `reliply.org` to verify and then to our site and still same response code. I just set the user-agent to the device browser user-agent and still no luck. The device's browser was able to access our url. I appreciate all the help you're providing! If you have any other ideas or want to see anything let me know. If I resolve then I'll give you the answer so I can accept yours.

Comment: try this: host your page on localhost or Google App Engine https://appengine.google.com/.. and see if you can access that... if that works then may the issue would be with the server provider...

Comment: Using a friends personal site with a different web host it worked as is, I re-opened my ticket with surpasshosting, they must be blocking something in my header.

Comment: ok.... you can also ask about any recent change they have done to block requests...

Comment: I found out that it was a script matching a rule in `mod_security`, I had them disable and now everything works again. Sorry about dragging you through this. If you want to change your answer to something relative to what I've found then I will mark as accepted.

Comment: I would suggest you to post your solution as answer and accept it so that other can benefit from that in future..